# Joining Solr cores in Datastax Enterprise null value error

Tags: solr, cassandra

I am trying to join two Solr cores using this:

> http://localhost:8983/solr/keyspace.solr_table1/select/?q={!join+fromIndex=keyspace.solr_table2}name:Doe&indent=true&wt=json&force=true

The column families in Cassandra have the same keyspace, but they do not have the same partition key (the name differs and the datatype also). The first column family has a partition key 'id'(int) and the second is 'id_text' (bigint). My search is in the column 'name'(secondary index, same column name in both column families) and I am using force=true.

The result of this is:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"{!join fromIndex=keyspace.solr_table1}name:Doe",
      "indent":"true",
      "force":"true",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "error":{
    "msg":"undefined field: \"null\"",
    "code":400},
  "params":"q={!join+fromIndex%3Dkeyspace.solr_table2}name:Doe&indent=true&force=true&wt=json"}
```

If I do a simple search in both cores I have results:

> http://localhost.40:8983/solr/keyspace.solr_table1/select?q=nom%3ADoe&wt=json&indent=true

Both column families contain null values in the secondary index: name, will that possibly be a reason why the join will not work? If so, is there a way to tell to just ignore if there are null values and make the join on the values that are not null?

The DSE version is 4.8.
The schema for the first core is:

```
 <schema name="solr_quickstart" version="1.1">
 <types>
  <fieldType name="bigint" class="solr.TrieLongField"/>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField"/>
 </types>
 <fields>
<field name="id_individu" type="int" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="nom" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="prenom" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="nom_conjoint" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="prenom_conjoint" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="id_gedcom" type="bigint" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="all" type="string" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
 </fields>

<defaultSearchField>nom</defaultSearchField>
<uniqueKey>(id_individu)</uniqueKey>
<copyField source="nom" dest="all"/>
<copyField source="prenom" dest="all"/>
<copyField source="nom_conjoint" dest="all"/>
<copyField source="prenom_conjoint" dest="all"/>
<copyField source="id_gedcom" dest="all"/>

</schema>
```

and the schema for the second core is

```
    <schema name="solr_quickstart" version="1.1">
 <types>
  <fieldType name="bigint" class="solr.TrieLongField"/>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField"/>
 </types>
 <fields>
<field name="id" type="bigint" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="nom" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="prenom" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="nom_conjoint" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="prenom_conjoint" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="id_gedcom" type="bigint" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="all" type="string" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
 </fields>

<defaultSearchField>nom</defaultSearchField>
<uniqueKey>(id)</uniqueKey>
<copyField source="nom" dest="all"/>
<copyField source="prenom" dest="all"/>
<copyField source="nom_conjoint" dest="all"/>
<copyField source="prenom_conjoint" dest="all"/>
<copyField source="id_gedcom" dest="all"/>

</schema>
```

Thank you so much for any input!

Comment: Can you provide DSE version and both table schemas please?

Comment: I edited my initial post and added the schema for both cores and the DSE version (4.8)

Answer (score 0):

If you run it without the 'force' option you get the following message:

> "The joined Solr cores must have the same partition key validators; the from core has: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType; the to core has: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type\nIf you want to force the join, pass force=true as a local parameter."

which is aligned to what the docs specify as requirements for the join to work at [DSE join docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchQueryJoin.html)

So I'm afraid you'll have to fine tune things around if you want to join. You might also want to use version 1.5 for the solr schema.

Also if you want to use the 'force' param you need to change the syntax. Check DSE docs to see what is the correct syntax when using 'force'.

Still the error message when forcing the join should be better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try adding an extra id column for one of the tables in order to have the same partition key. I used the proper syntax for force = true, but I do get the same error.